# Trying to add image changer in js

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

My goal is to have the image switch once it's been clicked and back again to the original image once the second image has been clicked again. I hope that makes sense. I've been trying this for two days with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

/* global document */

```
var cactusImage = document.querySelector('img');

cactusImage.onclick = function () {
  var myImages = cactusImage.getAttribute('src');
  if(myImages === 'images/cactus.jpg') {
    cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/old-typewriter');
  } else {
    cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/cactus.jpg')    
  }
```

}

---

```
<head> <!-- Content in the head element will not be displayed by browers-->  
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Sample webpage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheets/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
 
</head>

<body>
    
    <h1>Hello World !</h1> <!-- the size can be changed with css-->  

    <!-- <p class="para">It's a start of a new day</p>-->
    <img src="images/cactus.jpg" alt="cactus">
    <p class="para">Let us try to be</p>
    <ul>
        <!-- this is an unordered list--> 
    
        <li> Kind</li>
        <li> Time</li>
        <li> Why</li>
        <li> Who</li>
    
    
    </ul>
    
    <p id="quote">The plan is to create a site that looks like this <a href="http://truecrimediary.com/">one</a>, which was created by a popular mystery writier.</p>
    
 
    <!-- <script>
    
    var myHeading = document.querySelector("h1")
    
    myHeading.textContent = 'Be Kind' ;
    
    </script> -->

</body>
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works, can you show the entire code may be missed something somewhere

Comment: Of course. The code I provided was on a separate js. folder. From the example I provided, it was written in class, the instructor had us create the code in a separate js. outside of the HTML.

Comment: Here is the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="switchImg()">
        <img src="img1.png" id="img">
    </a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
        var imgSrc = document.getElementById("img").src
        function switchImg() {
            if(imgSrc == "img1.png") {
               document.getElementById("img").src = "img2.png";
               imgSrc = document.getElementById("img").src;
            }
        }
```

Just replace the names of the image files.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll implement the code tonight and have an update later this week.

Comment: I see the code you presented is for the HTML, but I wrote the code listed in the question in a myscripts.js file. I'll still try it, but I wanted to keep the code in the js. folder if possible.

Comment: I know you already have a solution but I edited the answer for anybody else who sees this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code. There is one error in your code i.e., you haven't mentioned the file extension whether its in .jpg or any other format in setAttribute. So let's say if your old-typewriter is in jpg format than this code will work if you have another format of image just replace jpg with that format and try to rerun this code.

```
    var cactusImage = document.querySelector('img');
    cactusImage.onclick = function () {
      var myImages = cactusImage.getAttribute('src');
      if(myImages === 'images/cactus.jpg') {
        cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/old-typewriter.jpg');
      } else {
        cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/cactus.jpg')    
      }
    }
```

I have edited complete code and you can replace your code with below code. It will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <!-- Content in the head element will not be displayed by browers-->  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Sample webpage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheets/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Hello World !</h1> <!-- the size can be changed with css-->  

    <!-- <p class="para">It's a start of a new day</p>-->
    <img src="images/cactus.jpg" alt="cactus">
    <p class="para">Let us try to be</p>
    <ul>
        <!-- this is an unordered list--> 
    
        <li> Kind</li>
        <li> Time</li>
        <li> Why</li>
        <li> Who</li>
    
    
    </ul>
    
    <p id="quote">The plan is to create a site that looks like this <a href="http://truecrimediary.com/">one</a>, which was created by a popular mystery writier.</p>

</body>
<script>
    var cactusImage = document.querySelector('img');
    cactusImage.onclick = function () {
      var myImages = cactusImage.getAttribute('src');
      if(myImages === 'images/cactus.jpg') {
        cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/old-typewriter.jpg');
      } else {
        cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/cactus.jpg');  
      }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll try this code later this week and will let you know if it works. I appreciate the help!

Comment: So I put in the code you suggested and was hit with an (unexpected token) error, which stopped the scan.

Comment: I have tried it. Please remove pre tags if you have added it inside script tag or just simply copy my edited code and just replace .jpg with your old-typewriter image format.Please let me know.

Comment: if you can share me the image format of old-typewriter image i can send u complete fixed code.

Comment: Thanks, Vipul. I'm going to input the code you suggested regarding the .jpg I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Holy-moly! So I took "Vipul's" suggestion of wrapping the code in script> and embedding the code in my HTML file which I wasn't doing before and voila. I want to thank all of you for the suggestions made. I hope I can return the favor one day.

Best,

```
<head> <!-- Content in the head element will not be displayed by browers-->  
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Sample webpage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheets/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    

 
</head>

<body>
    
    <h1>Hello World !</h1> <!-- the size can be changed with css--> 
    
    

    <!-- <p class="para">It's a start of a new day</p>-->
    <img src="images/cactus.jpg" alt="cactus">
    <p class="para">Let us try to be</p>
    <ul>
        <!-- this is an unordered list--> 
    
        <li> Kind</li>
        <li> Time</li>
        <li> Why</li>
        <li> Who</li>
    
    
    </ul>
    
    <p id="quote">The plan is to create a site that looks like this <a href="http://truecrimediary.com/">one</a>, which was created by a popular mystery writier.</p>
    
    <button>Change name</button>
    
    <script src="scripts/myscripts.js"> </script>
    
    <script>
var cactusImage = document.querySelector('img');
cactusImage.onclick = function () {
  var myImages = cactusImage.getAttribute('src');
  if(myImages === 'images/cactus.jpg') {
    cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/old-typewriter.jpg');
  } else {
    cactusImage.setAttribute ('src','images/cactus.jpg');  
  }
}
```

var myHeading = document.querySelector("h1")
        
        myHeading.textContent = 'Be Kind' ;
        
         -->